# Apple "approve" adding UIViews inside non-documented Views?

Tags: iphone

Apple submission app approves when we add UIView inside non-documented UIViews?
I mean,

```
// search for non-documented subview...
UIView *nv = ... //non-documented view;
[nv addSubview:myNormalView];
```

Is that ok to Apple?

Thanks.
Hami

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by non documented you mean views or UI elements that are part of the SDK but are not documented in apples public api (such as UIGlassButton) then no, its not ok with apple and if they find you are using them they will most likely reject your app. However if you just mean a subclass of UIView created by yourself or someone else, then its ok.

Comment: Yes, i mean views like UIGlassButton. I would like to put buttons inside UIKeyboard. I that ok for Apple?

Answer (score 0):

A lot of folks did this sort of thing to get around the lack of custom UI support when taking pictures using the camera with iPhone SDK 2.0. Several apps that dug through the view hierarchy and changed it were approved for distribution via the store. At least one was a "featured" app for a while.

It was/is against the SDK rules to do so, and several other applications were rejected from the App Store for doing exactly this sort of thing. Ultimately, it's a total crap-shoot. Whether or not the person who reviews your application notices that you're doing something you shouldn't will determine whether or not you "get away with it".

Comment: Ok. Again, i will make lots of line code to make a simple things with iPhon sdk.. :( Thanks anyway.